# Rectangle not showing in PyGame window

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = 320, 240
black = 0, 0, 0
red = 255, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

screen.fill(black)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (10,10,50,50))
pygame.display.flip()
```

But it is not actually creating a rectangle in the PyGame window.

Answer (score 2):

How you draw your rectangle is correct. You just need to constantly call the `pygame.display.flip()` in a while loop to render your game.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = 320, 240
black = 0, 0, 0
red = 255, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

screen.fill(black)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (10,10,50,50))
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]